# Laravel Api response

Tags: api, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and Api development, i am facing a problem, the workflow of my api is, a user sends post data to api, then api takes that data and processes the data to databases, now there is a process in which php waits for 30 min. while inserting data into two different tables. 
The problem is as far as i know after that process is complete then only i can send json response back to user. but this way user has to wait for 30 minute.

Is there a way that process that takes 30 min do work in background and send the response json immediately when that process started ?

1) I studied about queues but the web server i will be hosting will not give me access to server as a whole to install something, it will only give me space for my files.

I am confused how to achieve this functionality, so that user do not have to wait much for Response.

I will really appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: Deferring the data processing to queues is the practical way to do this. Laravel offers a [`database` driver for queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#introduction), which means you don't need to install additional services such as beanstalk, redis, etc to handle queues, so you should be fine if the hosting provider doesn't allow you to install anything.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, I studied about this, i also thought to use queues, but one task in those 30 minute is api call to google cloud messaging, will that also work. Moreover can you please provide me the link for queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `queue` without any server installation. All your configuration goes in the `config/queue.php` file.

You can use

- Amazon SQS: aws/aws-sdk-php ~3.0
- Beanstalkd: pda/pheanstalk ~3.0
- Redis: predis/predis ~1.0

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#introduction

Comment: so can i use jobs for calling another apis also ( e.g. google cloud message)

Comment: If you don't want the user to wait, yes. you can

Comment: Thanks Jilson, will try and comment

Comment: Jilson, I have a small question, can't we use threads for doing the background work, i mean create thread for the task and return Json Response. I am really novice.

Comment: `Thread` is actually a program in execution. `Queue` actually helps you to buffer the data to be processed by the thread. So queue helps you to feed your thread in a way.

Comment: Thanks Jilson, really appreciate

Comment: You can mark this answer as completed if you found this as a solution.